# Create Keycloak JS based policy with path variable in quarkus

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

Creating JS based policy on keycloak server. I need to fetch the amount from requested uri and create policy based on that in quarkus-keycloak-application.

This is my sample uri.

```
/api/amount-withdrawal/{amount}
```

Mapping path to keycloak server `application.properties`

```
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.name=Amount Withdrawal
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.path=/api/amount-withdrawal/{amount}/*
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.paths.1.claim-information-point.claims.claim-from-relativePath={request.relativePath}
```

js policy

```
var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var identity = context.getIdentity();
var attributes = identity.getAttributes();
var amount = attributes.getValue('?');
print(amount);
```

I am facing an issue to get amount from uri in js policy. I refer this keycloak [quickstart](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-employee) but its in spring boot then how to implement it in quarkus.

Thanks

Comment: my mistake, replace ```var attributes = identity.getAttributes();``` with ```var attributes = context.getAttributes();```